# An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'masterpage.fileupload'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, file-upload, asp.net-4.0

I am using a static method to upload my image in the project folder but not able to do so as I am getting the error :

> An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'inheritedclass.fileupload'

My function is as follows:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string FileUploadUsingJqueryNew(string nameofimage)
{
    string File_Name = nameofimage;       
    FileUploadID.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/UploadFile/" + File_Name));
    imgID.ImageUrl = "../UploadFile/" + File_Name;
    imgID.Visible = true;
    return nameofimage;
}
```

Comment: You have so many error in your code.

Comment: Your code is not real. Please, provide a real sample for futher help.

Answer (score 2):

You use [FileUpload.SaveAs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx) method of WebControl, which is on your page. Your page is a object with properties, one of them is your `FileUpload`.

You can't pass a reference for your control to the static method. You can use only non-static method to use your `FileUpload` control.

**Update:**
According that you are using `[WebMethod]` attribute, I think you are trying to pass your file to the Web-Service method. This can be done by adding a `FileUpload` handler passing contents of your file to the `[WebMethod]` as `Stream` using [HttpPostedFile.InputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx).

Comment: Yes through the [WebMethod] I am getting the name of the image. Now what I have to do is only save that image in a folder contained in my solution named UploadFile.

Comment: @user1621830 You can't pass ONLY a string to the file - you need either to pass Stream for your file, or save a file into temporary path.

Answer (score 1):

- `FileName = nameofimage`

You can't define a `Filename` like this. `FileName` is a property.  Use like this `String fileName = FileUpload1.FileName;` **Don't forget the comma!**

- `FileUpload.SaveAs()`

You can't do it. You can use it with non-static method in [`FileUpload`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. Use like this;

```
FileUpload f = new FileUpload();
f.SaveAs();
```

Comment: I am getting the full path of the image as well as the image name, but its not saving when I am writing the f.saveas(full path string) method inside the static function